# Abrir un form modal en un hilo aparte y luego cerrarlo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Al iniciar mi aplicación, a través de un background worker abro un formulario modal en un hilo de ejecución nuevo, mientras en el hilo principal se traen datos de una base de datos SQL Server.

Cuando termina el proceso de traer esos datos, se muestra el formulario principal de la aplicación

PROBLEMA: no logro hacer cerrar el formulario modal.

CÓDIGO:

```
public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
{

    List<string> _nodosMarcados = new List<string>();
    bool _interrumpir = false;
    BackgroundWorker worker; // Este es el bw que utilizo para el hilo nuevo
    frmIniciando _modalInicio = new frmIniciando(); // Este es el formulario modal



    public frmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_StopWorking;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _modalInicio.ShowDialog();
    }

    // En el Load del Form principal va toda la lógica para traer los datos de la BD, 
    // y al final intento cerrar el form modal con _modalInicio.Close(), pero no se cierra
```

EDITO:

Agrego una aclaración sobre lo que quiero hacer: el cuadro de dialogo del principio muestra un mensaje "Cargando aplicación..", lo que yo quiero es que al terminar de cargar el form principal, que se cierre ese cuadro.

Por que lo estoy haciendo en un nuevo hilo de ejecución? Porque el hilo principal está ocupado trayendo la info de la BD.

Por qué utilizo ShowDialog en lugar de Show para mostrar el cuadro? Porque con Show no me lo muestra. Lo carga pero queda como invisible y cuando termina de cargar el principal desaparece pero nunca lo llego a ver en pantalla. Con ShowDialog lo veo correctamente pero no se como cerrarlo.

Comment: Te da algun error? Y donde esta el codigo de cerrar el form?

Comment: @Einer no me da error, simplemente queda abierto. No publiqué el código para cerrar el form porque es muy largo, para cerrarlo, simplemente en el evento Load del Form principal, cuando termino de obtener los datos de la BD, hago _modalInicio.Close();

Comment: me parece que tenes un problema al llamar a showdialog.. showdialog no tiene un close, lleva un dispose directamente.. lo que pasa.. es que si esta en otro thread.. no se como se comporta.. me parece que el dialogo deberia estar en el thread principal, y el secundario hacer las cargas...

Comment: @gbianchi no podría hacer eso porque como en el proceso de traer los datos de la BD los estoy volcando a varios controles, me da error porque los controles fueron declarados en un hilo diferente y me arroja una excepción.

Comment: pero se pueden pasar cosas entre hilos! no recuerdo el codigo de memoria pero se puede.. e igual.. no deberias ir guardando todo en clases y despues llenar el form.. e igual, para que disparar un form modal y cargarlo en segundo plano.. si el usuario igual no peude hacer nada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera (por si a alguien le sirve):

En lugar de usar un background worker, utilicé hilos:

```
ThreadStart proceso = new ThreadStart(MostrarCuadroInicio);
Thread hilo = new Thread(proceso);
hilo.Start();

// CODIGO QUE SE EJECUTA MIENTRAS MUESTRO EL CUADRO MODAL

hilo.Abort();
```

El método "MostrarCuadroInicio" hace lo siguiente:

```
private void MostrarCuadroInicio()
{
    frmIniciando _modalInicio = new frmIniciando("Iniciando aplicación ...", true);
    _modalInicio.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: esa solución también me sirvió para lo que quería hacer.

Comment: Solución genial y elegante. Yo al formulario le añadí el control CircularProgressBar que aparece en este video (https://youtu.be/o7MGaf8YW6s).

Comment: Excelente me sirvio.